# Always, and automatically, keep all branch information is possible?

Tags: git, git-branch

I know that With

```
$ git merge --no-ff hello-branch
```

I can keep all information of "hello-branch". But There is a way to set "--no-ff" inside my global .gitconfig? Or maybe inside configuration of current .git/config file?

Answer (score 3):

See `git help config`:

```
   merge.ff
       By default, Git does not create an extra merge commit when merging a
       commit that is a descendant of the current commit. Instead, the tip of the
       current branch is fast-forwarded. When set to false, this variable tells
       Git to create an extra merge commit in such a case (equivalent to giving
       the --no-ff option from the command line). When set to only, only such
       fast-forward merges are allowed (equivalent to giving the --ff-only option
       from the command line).
```